# Use shapepar for beamer titlepage

Tags: beamer, shapepar

Looking for a solution to avoid arithmetic error while trying to get `tikz` and `shapepar` working together.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz,shapepar}

\setbeamertemplate{title page}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
%\node[circle,fill=black,text=white] {\shapepar{\circleshape} \inserttitle\par}; % <- not working
\end{tikzpicture}}

\title{Some title with variable length}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{frame}
\shapepar{\circleshape} \huge\inserttitle % <- working fine here
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

According to David, this should be the syntax: `\node[shape=circle,text width=0cm, fill=black,text=white] {\shapepar{\circleshape} \inserttitle\par};`, with `text width=0cm` so that the node scales with the content. Anyhow, depending on the length of `\inserttitle`, I still encounter arithmetic overflow.

Comment: You can't specify 0pt: shapepar needs a target width for linebreaking?

Comment: I guess it'll set the best linewidth by itself...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

a node is an `\hbox` and can't have paragraph things unless you specify either `text width` or `align=<...>` keys (when it becomes a `minipage` environment)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz,shapepar}

\setbeamertemplate{title page}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[text width=6cm, fill=black,text=white] {\shapepar{\circleshape} \inserttitle\par}; % <- not working
\end{tikzpicture}}

\title{Some title with variable length}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{frame}
\shapepar{\circleshape} \huge\inserttitle % <- working fine here
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

or a version with a long title and the division operator modified so it never overflows (just returns `\maxdimen`

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz,shapepar}
\makeatletter
\def\fpdivide#1#2{%
\@tempcntb #2\relax
\multiply\@tempcntb10
#1=\dimexpr(#1*\p@ /\@tempcntb) \relax
\ifdim#1>0.1\maxdimen
#1=\maxdimen
\else
\multiply#1 by 10
\fi
}

\makeatother

\setbeamertemplate{title page}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[text width=8cm, fill=black,text=white] {\shapepar{\circleshape} \inserttitle\par}; % <- not working
\end{tikzpicture}}

\title{Some title with variable length
x x x x x x x x x x x
very very long
very very long
very very long
very very long
very very long
}
\begin{document}


\maketitle

\begin{frame}
\shapepar{\circleshape} \huge\inserttitle % <- working fine here
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What about the arithmetic overflow? (`\fpdivide ...1=\dimexpr #1*\p@ /\@tempcntb \relax`)

Comment: @s__C I got no overflow on the document as posted (texlive 2014) what versions are you using?

Comment: MacTeX 2014 here. Have you tried increasing the length of `\title`?

Comment: @s__C the question is supposed to provide an example that demonstrates the problem:-) I'll add some words....

Comment: Like this: "Some title with variable length all across the titlepage even with a very long title"...

Comment: @s__C try  now, added some rescaling

Comment: Brilliant! This works perfectly.